# Keep Image covered in div on resize

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a fullscreen layer with 2 rows and different amount of columns.
The idea is to fill the divs with the image no matter how you resize the window.

Resizing works for the divs but not for the image :-(

I don't want to work with backgound-image:cover in the div because I want to toggle the image to a video later on.

Anybody got a clue on this?

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var h = $( window ).height(); // returns height of browser viewport
    var w = $( window ).width(); // returns height of browser viewport

    var hproject = h/2 ;     
    var wcontstart = w - 25 ;  

    $("#menu-inhalt").css({ width: wcontstart , height: h });
    $("#bereiche li").animate({ height: hproject });
    $("img").css({ height: hproject });


});
```

/* RESIZE */

```
$( window ).resize(function() {

    var h = $( window ).height(); // returns height of browser viewport
    var w = $( window ).width(); // returns height of browser viewport

    var hproject = h/2 ;     
    var wcontstart = w - 25 ;  

    $("#menu-inhalt").css({ width: wcontstart , height: h });   

    $("#bereiche li").css({ height: hproject });    

    $("img").css({ height: hproject });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hsBPp/1/

Thanks!!

Comment: How about background-size:100% 100%; for that div.

Comment: Well, I am not working with background images, it is <img src="">

Answer (score 0):

Just add this class in your css. Image will cover the div full width.

```
#bereiche img{width:100%;}
```

Comment: I tried this before, this has the effect that the image stretches and loses it proportions when resizing the window :-(

Comment: so how u want? you want to cut the part of image to cover in proportioned manner.

Comment: I would like to have it like on this page [link]http://hlkagency.com/About when you click menu. - images, columns, rows keep their proportions when resizes + effect play video on mouseenter.